# Add custom properties/values to a Google Apps Acount via Admin SDK

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

Best way to add custom information to a Google Account via AdminSDK

I will add custom information to accounts in Apps, what would be the best practice? Im thinking of adding the data to "ims" were I can add custom types, any feedback on that, is there any better way/more suitable properties?

In this exmaple i need to add a "internalBussinesNumber" with value= "7497261_DK", could this be done like this? I just need to GET/Retrieve this info later for another system via Google API/JSON.

```
"ims": [
    {
      "type": custom,
      "customType": "internalBussinesNumber",
      "protocol": custom_protocol,
      "customProtocol": "internalBussinesNumber",
      "im": "7497261_DK",
      "primary": false
    }
  ],
```

Could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to do this would be to use the newly announced [Custom User Schemas](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-schemas).

```
"customSchemas": {
  "employmentData": {
   "employeeNumber": "123456789",
   "jobFamily": "Engineering"
   "location": "Atlanta",
   "jobLevel": 8,
   "projects": [
    { "value": "GeneGnome", "customType": "development" },
    { "value": "Panopticon", "customType": "support" }
   ]
  }
 }
```

Comment: Just wondering if you tried this. We are trying right now, using the API explorer. Both a patch and update request state in the response the updated customSchemas but a get does not reflect these changes and the profile is never really updated.